# Encoding.GetString from Stream

Tags: .net

I have a function that converts a part of stream to a string:

```
private string GetString(Stream stream, int start, int length) 
{
    var buffer = new byte[length];
    stream.Read(buffer, start, length);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, start, length);
}
```

I am working with pretty big stream and I don't like to duplicate bytes (by converting part of stream to byte[]) just for being able to call `Encoding.GetString`. Is there any way to get string of some encoding from stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do - and the fact that you're calling `Stream.Read` without using the return value is alarming - but perhaps you're looking for [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)? It's a [`TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) which is backed by a `Stream`, so you can read characters from it instead of binary data. This is appropriate if you're reading from a stream which is entirely text data (at least from the current position when you pass is to the constructor; it could have binary data earlier).

If you're *really* trying to read data from just part of a stream, your code needs changing anyway - `Stream.Read` doesn't do what you think it does in terms of the second parameter, which is the position *within the buffer*, not the position within the stream. You'd need to use `Stream.Position` or `Stream.Seek()` to get to the right position in the stream.